How does Newtonian gravity work in a toroidal universe?
Suppose that the universe is not isotropic, so we can fix directions $x,y,z$. Furthermore, suppose there are periodic boundary conditions such that we identify $x\sim x+L$ and $y\sim y+L$ (similar to the topology of a 2-torus). Work in the framework of Newtonian gravity.
Suppose we fix a test mass $m$ at the origin. What is the gravitational force exerted by the mass at some other point $(x,y,z)$? Clearly, it cannot be the usual formula because there must be an equilibrium at $(L/2,0,0)$, for example.
My gut instinct is that the resulting force can be found by considering an infinite lattice of masses $m$ at locations $(mL,nL,0)$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and applying Newton's formula with all of those masses. Is this correct, and if so, why?

For context, that is the approach in cosmological simulations of a periodic volume (technically implemented as Ewald summation).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867634/fundamental-solution-of-poisson-equation-on-the-torus might be useful. On just a torus there is no solution, but I don't know how that applies when one dimension is infinite.

@Javier gravity is different because the equivalence principle means potentials that differ by a linear term (not just a constant) are equivalent. That means a solution on the torus is possible, with the potential changing by such a term over a cycle. (But the size of the torus has to evolve appropriately for this to work.)
